# What is the theory behind the Light Glow effect of "After Effects"?

Tags: image-processing, glsl, shader, image-manipulation, after-effects

What is the theory behind the Light Glow effect of "After Effects"?
I wanna use GLSL to make it happen. But if I at least get closer to the theory behind it, I could replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question just in case someone gets to here at the same point. With more precision (actually 100% of precision) I got to the exact After Effects's glow. The way it works is:

1. Apply a gaussian blur to the original image.
2. Extract the luma of this blurred image
3. Like in After Effects, you have two colors (A and B). So the secret is to make a gradient map between these color, acoording to the desired "Color Looping". If you don't know, a gradient map is an interpolation between colors (A and B in this case). Following the same vocabulary of After Effects, you need to loop X times over the "Color Looping" you chose... it means, suppose you are using the Color Looping like A->B->A, it will be considered one loop over your image (one can try this on Photoshop).
4. Take the luma your extract on step 2 and use as a parameter of your gradient map...  in other words: luma=(0%, 50%, 100%) maps to color (A, B, A) respectively... the mid points are interpolated.
5. Blend your image with the original image according to the "Glow Operation" desired (Add, Multiply, etc)

This procedure work like After Effects for every single pixel. The other details of the Glow may be easily done after in basic procedure... things like "Glow Intensity", "Glow Threshold" and so on needs to be calibrated in order to get the same results with the same parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently been implementing something similar.  My render pipeline looks something like this:

1. Render Scene to texture (full screen)
2. Filter scene ("bright pass") to isolate the high luminance, shiny bits
3. Down-sample (2) to smaller texture (for performance), and do H Gaussian blur
4. Perform a V Gaussian blur on (3).
5. Blend output from (4) with the output from (1)
6. Display to screen.

With some parameter tweaking, you get get it looking pretty nice.  Google things like "bright pass" (low pass filter), Gaussian Blur, FBO (Frame Buffer Objects) and so on.  Effects like "bloom" and "HDR" also have a wealth of information about different ways of doing each of these things.  I tried out about 4 different ways of doing Gaussian blur before settling on my current one.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how to make shadow volumes, and instead of stenciling out a shadow, you could run a multi-pass blur on the volume, set its material to a very emissive, additive blended shader, and I imagine you'll get a similar effect.

Atlernatively, you could do the [GPUGems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html) implementation: